# Generating Xml a very specific way

Tags: c#, xml

- I have specific xml files and I need to be able to adopt a c# class/code that conforms to them (Both reading and writing). Not the other way around. I know I could do tricks like first opening the file, replacing the root name and such, but I want to learn to do it write perhaps using xml overrides or other xml configuration/identifier themes properly used in the class or over the array.

I tried to do things with the xml overrides, but I couldn't get it right.

**SAMPLE CODE THAT GENERATES THE OUTPUTS**

Here is a sample code:

```
 public class TestXml
    {
        public TestXmlElement[] testXmlArray = new TestXmlElement[] { new TestXmlElement(),new TestXmlElement() };
        public TestXml() { }
    }
    public class TestXmlElement
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name = "default";
        [XmlAttribute]
        public ulong Value = 1;
        public TestXmlElement() { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestXml tx=new TestXml();
            StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter(@"g:\test_class.xml");
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXml));
            x.Serialize(sw.BaseStream, tx);
            sw.Close();

            TestXmlElement[] txa = new TestXmlElement[] { new TestXmlElement(),new TestXmlElement() };
            sw = new StreamWriter(@"g:\test_array.xml");
            x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXmlElement[]));
            x.Serialize(sw.BaseStream, txa);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUTS**

This is what is in test_class.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestXml>
  <testXmlArray>
    <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
    <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
  </testXmlArray>
</TestXml>
```

This is what is in test_array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfTestXmlElement>
  <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
  <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
</ArrayOfTestXmlElement>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

This is what I need (Without the array layer if used by class, or overridden array idendifier if writing the array itself):
(If array layer was not there in class case, then I could name the class properly no problem. The problem writing the class is that extra layer of < testXmlArray >)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOME_OVERRIDDEN_NAME>
  <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
  <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
</SOME_OVERRIDDEN_NAME>
```

Comment: Unclear for me, can you provide, clearly, your input, the output you get and the expected output?

Comment: Well, ok! Added some bold font texts to segregate them...

Comment: When XML Serializing an array Net library will automatically create two layers of XML tags.  To eliminate the extra tag you need to add above the array : [XmlElement("TestXmlElement")]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your `TestXml` class as an `IList<TestXmlElement>` implementation:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SOME_OVERRIDDEN_NAME")]
public class TestXml : IList<TestXmlElement>
{
    private List<TestXmlElement> _innerList = new List<TestXmlElement>();
    public TestXmlElement this[int index] { get => _innerList[index]; set => _innerList[index] = value; }
    public int Count => _innerList.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    -- snip rest of IList members
}
```

Then:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestXml tx = new TestXml();
        tx.Add(new TestXmlElement());
        tx.Add(new TestXmlElement());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\testproj\test_class.xml");
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXml));
        x.Serialize(sw.BaseStream, tx);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOME_OVERRIDDEN_NAME xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
  <TestXmlElement Name="default" Value="1" />
</SOME_OVERRIDDEN_NAME>
```

Comment: I am going to add jdweng's answer here as well, because it does the job. Both answers are great.

When XML Serializing an array Net library will automatically create two layers of XML tags. To eliminate the extra tag you need to add above the array : [XmlElement("TestXmlElement")]